# Star icon still appears on Gmail messages even after using Apps Script to unstar them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am running an apps script that searches my Gmail for unread + starred messages with a particular label. The script then completes a few tasks and finally marks the messages as read and unstarred. The starred messages don't appear in the starred folder anymore, and GmailApp service in Apps Script doesn't identify them as starred, but they still *appear* to have a star in my Gmail ui. Why is this?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function myCode () {

  var payments = GmailApp.search('is:unread is:starred label:"Payments"');

  /** I do some things */

  for (var i in payments) {
    
    var message = payments[i].getMessages()[0];

    message.unstar();

    message.markRead();

  }

}
```

This seems to mostly work: the messages are marked as read and disappear from my starred folder (on my iPhone and the Gmail ui on my laptop). I also have tried logging  message.isUnread() + message.isStarred(), and both return false.

BUT — the messages still have a star on them in the Gmail ui, even though they don't appear in the starred folder. Why is that? I spoke with a GMAIL help specialist, and they said that their internal logs show that my api was *STARRING* the messages...which I don't understand.

Interestingly—When I view the Gmail UI in html view, the stars don't appear, but they do appear in regular view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this apply to you: [Gmail Unstar Issue through Google App Script ](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232516751)
  (from the Google issue tracker)